# Create a redundant model for sake of the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `Booking` has many `Shifts` (each has a custom start date, start time, end date, and end time).

`Shifts` each have many `Appointments`, which are hour-long 'lego-blocks' of time.

I need to have `Booking`, and I need to have `Appointments`, but I don't really need to have `Shifts`. **The information in a `Shift` is duplicated in the `Appointments` it has.**

*So why have a shift?*

I want to add a "Create booking" view that allows a user to create a booking with multiple grouped `Appointments`. Ideally, here, the user sets the `Shift` properties (start date, etc), and you can add multiple `Shifts` to a booking if needed. This would be done with a `form_for` `Booking`, with `fields_for` shifts

It would be REALLY useful to be able to use a nested `fields_for` tag to create multiple shifts.

On submission of the form, the controller saves the required `Appointments`, disregards the `Shifts`.

Do I add this redundant middle model?

**Attempts at a solution**

My gut feeling is that I should create the model, but not controllers or views associated with it. I can use it as a "helper model" that never gets saved to the database.

Comment: What makes `Shift` useful or necessary? Or asked differently, what makes it preferable to creating `Appointments` directly in your "Create booking" view?

Comment: It makes it much easier to create a view. I want a view that is simply a form for Booking, with one or more nested forms for Shifts. If there is no such thing as a shift, I need some way to communicate which Appointments to build when the booking is created. Normally I'd use attr_accessor for fictitious values, but in this case, I don't know how many shifts will be created.

Comment: I'm still confused. You wrote that the information in `Shift` would be redundant? What function does it have — is it some kind of grouping? Do people book their appointments in shift A, B or C?

Comment: Fair, I'll attempt to clarify in the question

Comment: Thanks! And I am sorry to be daft and/or difficult, but that did not clarify it for me. If you could add rough outlines of which data your three models contain, that would be helpful. Should you happen to have a sketch, screenshot or mockup of your form, that might help as well.

Comment: Hi Janfoeh, sorry about my rubbish clarification! I've realised that there is unique information that needs to be contained in the "Shift" model, so this questions is moot and won't waste your time with this, but thank you, thank you, thank you for the help with it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out!